# Intersection two lines and SVD?

Tags: 3d, svd

Is it possible to calculate the intersection of two 3D lines using SVD?
What would it look like?

Thanks

Comment: You know that in general two 3D lines do not intersect...

Comment: Yes, but if they do, is svd of use?

Comment: This is a trivial problem to solve using basic vector algebra, only a handful of operations. Why would you try to use SVD here?  SVD can be used for finding the intersection of two or more subspaces, but lines are only subspaces if they pass through origin, and then origin would obviously be an intersection point.  I'm sure someone could Rube Goldberg a monstrosity of an expression that uses SVD in the solution, but what use would that be?

Comment: What is the meaning of "Rube Goldberg a monstrosity" in ordinary english ? Think to non-native english readers...

Comment: @BlabbotheVerbose: I just try to figure out how I would use SVD to solve linear equation. Many tutos out there, but I need to see by practice, because line intersection is a linear system resolution as well.. I though it could make it but apparently, no.

Comment: I am going to give an answer showing that SVD can be used in a certain way for this purpose.

Comment: @JeanMarie nice, thanks a lot, it is really helping me here to grasp the concept better !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider for example the system of 2 lines with resp. equations :

$$\begin{cases}x&=&0\\y&=&0\end{cases} \ \ \text{and} \ \ \begin{cases}y-z&=&0\\x&=&-a\end{cases}\tag{1}$$

where $a$ is a parameter. You have recognized in the first system the equations of the $z$ axis. The second represents a line with slope 1, parallel to (vertical) $x-z$ plane, at a distance $|a|$ from it.

Grouping the two systems in (1) into a single one gives rise to the following matrix :

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&1&-1&0\\1&0&0&-a\end{pmatrix}$$

The 4 singular values of $A$ depend a priori on the value of $a$ (see remark at the bottom). They are graphicaly represented below (for a range of $40$ values of $a$ which are $-2,-1.9,-1.8, \cdots 1.9, 2$ explaining the scale on the right ; we can see that for the value $a=0$ and for this value only (for which the two lines are coplanar), the smallest singular value is 0.

Due to the continuity of these singular values with repect to $a$, we see that when $a$ is small but not zero, it can trigger our attention and even give a way to measure the proximity (shortest distance) between the two lines.

[image]

Fig. 1: $\textit{Singular values sorted in decreasing order for different values of $a$.}$

Remark : This graphical representation can be misleading ; in fact, two of the singular values are constant, with resp. values $\Phi\approx 1.618$ and $\Phi-1 \approx 0.618$ where $\Phi$ denotes the golden ratio ; these constant values cannot be spotted at once because of the sorting of the singular values.  The two other singular values vary with formulas $\sigma = \sqrt{\frac12 \left(2+a^2 \pm \sqrt{a^4+4}\right)}$ which indeed can take value $0$ for $a=0$.

A somewhat better representation is this one :

[image]

Comment: I just found a research paper dealing with the general search of the intersection of two subspaces in $\mathbb{R}^n$ : https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8710372

Comment: Jean Marie, thanks a lot for your answer; in your matrix, to represent x -z = 0 in the third line, shouldn't it be [1 0 -1 0] instead of [0 1 -1 0] ?

Comment: Sorry, it was $y-z=0$ instead of $x-z=0$. I will fix it. Have you had a look at the paper whose reference I gave ? It looks interesting.

Comment: Yes! it is really nice and helped me grasp a lot more than expected! Thanks a lot Jean Marie

Comment: Just corrected an error in my last formula.

Comment: ... and added a different graphical representation.